# Don't assign data from fetch api

Tags: angular, observable

I am fetching my data from api in service. My problem is that the `console.log(this.planetsList);` in List Component is empty array. Why?

Here is my code
Service:

```
export class ListService {
      listUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets';
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getList(): Observable<Dummy> {
        return this.http.get<Dummy>(this.listUrl);
      }
    }
```

Main Component:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  public planetList: Planet[] = [];

  constructor(private listService: ListService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listService.getList().subscribe(list => {
      this.planetList = list.results;
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<app-list [planetsList]="planetList"></app-list>
```

List Component:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() planetsList: Planet[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.planetsList);
  }
}
```

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: try once without type i.e. `public planetList = [];`

Answer (score 1):

It's showing blank because Initially there is no any data. ngOnInit method called only one time. So here you have to use **ngOnChanges event.**

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() planetsList: Planet[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.planetsList);
  }
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input() planetsList: Planet[ ] = [ ];
```

Here, you are re-assigning the planetsList array to " [ ] " , which is empty.
Just do 
    Inlut() planetsList: Planet[ ] ;

Comment: Then i am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this question!

I think **the reason is async behavior** of the `Observable` in your case data from the API will be passed to the component twice. First time after the `MainComponent` initialization and it will be an empty array as you initialized in this line `public planetList: Planet[] = [];`, and the second one after you get a result of the GET response. So, after the `ngOnInit()` hook of the `ListComponent`, you will get an empty array.

You can manage this case with `ngOnChange()` hook it will be called twice (after every changing of the `@Input() planetsList: Planet[];` parameter. Or you can use the other option - usage the `async$` pipe.

You can find a more detailed explanation of the async pipe approach [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/).